# How to use If statement inside $.when().then() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using as an initialization of a JavaScript Controller a method which gets a parameter.Depending of the value of the parameter i use $.when() and then() methods to get data from ajax calls.

To be specific if the parameter that is passed is true inside $.when i would like to have 4 ajax calls and otherwise to have 3.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html"
    }).done(function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "test2.html"
    }).done(function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "test3.html"
    }).done(function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    }),
    if (config,EditMode) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test3.html"
        }).done(function () {
            $(this).addClass("done");
        })
    }
).then(function () {
    if (config,EditMode)
        somemethod();
    else
        someOtherMethod();
}).done(function () {
    //code
});
```

I try something like the above but i cant really make the syntax work.
Of course i could make a globally if else and just duplicate the code.
But i am going to get complaints from the DRY principle :)).

Do you have anything in mind?
Thanks

Comment: What do you think `this` is inside the callbacks. I bet it's not what you think.

Comment: And what is `if (config,EditMode)`?

Comment: that's not even valid JS

Comment: @phuzi it is if the two variables are defined (it would be the comma operator).  However I think it's just a typo for `.`

Comment: @Andreas the extra space got added when *you* reformatted the code.  It was probably supposed to read `config.EditMode`.

Comment: @Alnitak I obviously missed the space... :|

Comment: Guys that was just an example code to show my question.It has nothing to do with my code.cheers

Answer (score 5):

Don't put your `$.ajax` calls directly as parameters within your call to `$.when()`.

A simpler method would be to create an array of the individual promises:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push($.ajax(...));
promises.push($.ajax(...));
promises.push($.ajax(...));
if (config.EditMode) {
    promises.push($.ajax(...));
}
```

and then use `.apply` to pass the list:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(...);
```

This is a common way to call a function when you don't know in advance how many parameters you're going to be passing.

Comment: perfect that seems and much more cleaner.

Comment: @k.explorer But you still have to adjust the part with `$(this).addClass()`

Comment: @Andreas  that is just an example code to show my question .It is not even close to mine:))